# Update svgIcon component attribute after clicking

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I've made custom svgIcon component from SLDS tutorial to use icons in my Lightning components and apps.

I want to write controller that updates "svgPath" attribute after clicking, so my picture of my icon will change. I've impleneted var with my svgIcon component and used set method for this attribute but it doesn't worked.

```
<aura:component > 
  <c:svgIcon aura:id="icon" svgPath="/resource/slds213/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/‌​symbols.svg#account" category="standard" size="small" name="account" /> 
   <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon" aria-haspopup="true" onclick="{!c.changeIcon}"> 
      <c:svgIcon class="slds-icon-text-default" svgPath="/resource/slds213/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/s‌​ymbols.svg#down" category="utility" size="xx-small" name="down" /> 
   </button> 
 </aura:component >
```

Controller class

```
({ changeIcon : 
      function(cmp) { 
       var item = cmp.find('icon'); 
       item.set("v.svgPath", "/resource/slds213/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.‌​svg#user"); 
      } 
 })
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Would you mind showing us your current code?

Comment: I assume you are using a custom component for the svg creation and i believe you are using renderer method for creating the svg icon ?? Is this the case ?

Comment: `<aura:component >
 <c:svgIcon aura:id="icon" svgPath="/resource/slds213/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#account" category="standard" size="small" name="account" />
 <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon" aria-haspopup="true" onclick="{!c.changeIcon}">
  <c:svgIcon class="slds-icon-text-default" svgPath="/resource/slds213/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#down" category="utility" size="xx-small" name="down" />
 </button>
</aura:component >`

Comment: `({
 changeIcon : function(cmp) {
  var item = cmp.find('icon');
  item.set("v.svgPath", "/resource/slds213/assets/icons/standard-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#user");

 }

})`

Comment: Looks like you are making use of the trial head module which shows how to render svg as a custom component. However what it does not mention is the use of this.superRender and this.superReRender() .. kindly ensure you return this.superRender and this.superRerender() from the render and reRender methods respectively. Reference : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm

Comment: You have to put the xmlns on the containing div when re rendering or the page will stall

Comment: @Eric He is talking about lightning components and i guess he has that in his SVG component

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - Ok then, disregard. helpful tip though if you are trying to use SVG in a VF page

Answer (score 3):

Again the easiest way to do it is to use lightning:Icon from winter 17 release. 
Reference : [lightning:Icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm). This component will give you access to almost all the common svg icons used in the standard lightning design libraries ( includes action, custom, standard and utitly icons ) and also it gives you control over the size and variants.

So the implementation goes something like follows

[image]
[image: Lihgnting Icon Controller]

As mentioned earlier this would work well for almost all lightning design system icons. However if you want to use custom svg icons, then you must implement a custom implementation like follows

Reference : [Custom Svg Icons using Renderer Methods](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/)

If you notice this version of svg icon custom component uses helper methods to render the svg icon and append it to the DOM element and it returns this.superRender() as recommended in the documents below

Reference : [Renderer Life Cycle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm)